# UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent is creating a big white space

Tags: ios, swift, uiappearance

**UPDATE 2**:
I'm still hoping to get some help with this problem so I'm going to refine my question a little now that I've narrowed it down better.

My `UIViewController` hierarchy looks like this:

[image]

The filter view appears if the user touches the filter icon and selects a lift type. The image on the left is what it looks like without a filter selected and the right image is what it looks like with a filter selected. The navigation area (outlined in green) is what I'm trying to style.

[image]

Here's the thing I just can't figure out. If I add these two things:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(hexString: "232B35")
```

then a white space appears between the navigation area and the filter view:

[image]

If I set the translucent property to true, that white space doesn't appear, but then the barTintColor has no effect.

Note that I **didn't** put a `UINavigationBar` in my `UIViewController`. I only have a `UINavigationItem` that I'm adding with code.

At this point, my question is this - why is the big white space appearing out of nowhere when I have `UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false` in my code (and what can I do to get rid of it, but still change the color of my navigation area)?

I'm really stuck and would appreciate some help. Thanks!

**The following is my original question with information that may or may not be helpful:**
I'm trying to style my app and having a difficult time do so. On one `UIViewController` I've got a ThemeManager `struct` with a function that applies the theme to the app and in that method code that makes the navigation bar blend in with the background color of the app:

```
static func applyTheme(theme: Theme) {

    // set the background color
    sharedApplication.delegate?.window??.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "232B35")

    UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false // these are the offenders
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(hexString: "232B35")


    // first, set backgroundimage to nothing
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(
      UIImage(),
      forBarPosition: .Any,
      barMetrics: .Default)

    // and also set shadowimage to nothing
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()

    UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
    UILabel.appearance().textColor = UIColor(hexString: "768DAA")
    }
  }
```

My initial `ViewController` looks like I want it to - a background and navigation components that are the same color:

[image]

But on a different view controller, it's got this big space that I don't want:

[image]

And I've figured out that it's the `UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent` and `UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor` properties that are causing this to happen. It's as if it's adding a `UINavigationBar` underneath the actual navigation area. If I comment that code out, it doesn't have the color of course, but the big space I don't want goes away too:

[image]

The big difference between the two VCs are this: in the first VC which looks like I want, I intentionally placed a `UINavigationBar` via the storyboard but in the second VC I have not. I only placed a `UINavigationItem` in that one. Also note, the second VC contains a `UITableView` but it isn't a `UITableViewController`.

How can I get the solid color I want in the navigation area without adding this unwanted space underneath it?

**EDIT #1**
Here's another look at the `UIViewController` with the problem:

[image]

Notice the hierarchy is the `UIView` with the @IBOutlet connection, below that a `UIStackView` which contains the filter view (a `UIView`) that expands and collapses with a height layout constraint, and a `UITableView`. So the big white space that appears isn't even in my hierarchy.

In case it helps, here's the `viewDidLoad` method in the Lift Log's `UIViewController`:

class LiftLogViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

```
//MARK: IB outlets

  @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
  @IBOutlet weak var navItem: UINavigationItem!
  @IBOutlet weak var filterViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
  @IBOutlet weak var clearFilterButton: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var selectedFilter: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var clearButtonHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
  @IBOutlet weak var clearButtonView: UIImageView!

  let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack()
  var liftEvents = [LiftEvent]()
  var isFilterViewOpen = false

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissLog(_:)))

    let filterImage = UIImage(named: "filter_icon")
    let filterButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: filterImage, style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.actionFilter))

    self.navItem.rightBarButtonItems = [doneButton, filterButton]

    let buttonTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.clearFilter))
    clearFilterButton.addGestureRecognizer(buttonTap)

    filterViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0.0
    clearButtonHeightConstraint.constant = 0.0

    super.viewDidLoad()
  }
```

Comment: does your lift log vc contains TableView?

Comment: @Mr.UB, yes it does. Take a look at the edit I made to my question and you'll see more details about that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your `UINavigationBar` in the first VC `translucent` properties to false via storyboard to keep it consistent with your `UINavigationBar.appearance()`?

[image]

Then your second VC `Top Bar` should be inferring from the first VC.

[image]

Comment: Hi Zac, I didn't, but since you pointed it out I did make sure they're now consistent. Unfortunately, it didn't change the behavior.

I'm not sure if you caught it, but my 2nd VC doesn't have a `UINavigationBar`. I don't think it could infer anything from the 1st VC's `UINavigationBar`

Check out the additional info I've added to my question.